# Disable automatic bridging in some cases

Tags: objective-c, swift

From [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C - Working with Cocoa Frameworks](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html):

> Swift automatically converts some Objective-C types to Swift types, and some Swift types to Objective-C types.

But there are cases when automatic bridging is undesirable such as performance issues or due to bug in bridging implementation.

How can I disable this behaviour in specific cases? E.g. for specific statement or for specific class.

Comment: This happens only when you use the Swift type in Swift, and are interfacing with the Objective-C type. For instance, `NSArray` will bridge to Swift `Array` if you use `Array` in Swift and ask for something which produces `NSArray`. If you use `NSArray` directly in Swift, though, no bridging will happen. Does this not cover your use case?

Comment: @ItaiFerber I want to get `NSArray` (skipping bridging to `Array`) when I ask for something that produces `NSArray`.

Comment: `let myArray: NSArray = thingWhichProducesNSArray()` will not bridge

Comment: I rescind my answer for now — looks like I may be wrong. Will need to do further testing (and ask a coworker on Monday who knows better).

Answer (score 0):

I wish there is a `NS_DO_NOT_BRIDGE_FOR_SWIFT` macro but alas, it doesn't exist. Prowling through Swift's source code, I was not able to find that magic macro that disables bridging. The following answer is verbose. It relies on 2 facts:

1. Core Foundation types (i.e. `CF*`) are not bridged into Swift
2. There is toll-free bridging between Core Foundation (`CF*`) and Cocoa (`NS*`) types

Let's look at an example. First, the Objective-C side:

```
// MyClass.h
@interface MyClass : NSObject

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN
- (NSArray *)  randomNumbers NS_SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE("");  // mark this method as unavailable in Swift
- (CFArrayRef) cfRandomNumbers NS_REFINED_FOR_SWIFT;    // tell the compiler that you have a refined version for Swift
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END

@end

// MyClass.m
#import "MyClass.h"

@implementation MyClass

- (NSArray *) randomNumbers {
    return @[ @1, @2, @3 ];
}

- (CFArrayRef) cfRandomNumbers {
    return CFBridgingRetain([self randomNumbers]);  // toll-free
}

@end
```

The Swift side

```
extension MyClass {
    // Even though we marked `randomNumbers` as unavailable in Swift, we can't
    // use the same signature. Must name it something else.
    func objcRandomNumbers() -> NSArray {
        // Methods marked with NS_REFINED_FOR_SWIFT pick up
        // double-underscore prefix in their names
        return __cfRandomNumbers().takeUnretainedValue() as NSArray
    }
}

let obj = MyClass()
let arr = obj.objcRandomNumbers() // no bridging here
```

The upside is everything is documented and hence "official". You can check if bridging has ocurred by running the code through the Profiler.