# Swift/Obj-C interop: Prevent bridging of Foundation classes?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have an Obj-C category on NSLocale implementing these readonly properties:

```
@property (class, nonatomic, nonnull, readonly) NSLocale *searchLocale;
@property (nonatomic, nonnull, readonly) NSString *extendedLanguageCode;
```

Now when I wanna access it from Swift, I've to write `(NSLocale.search as NSLocale).extendedLanguageCode`. Is there a way to avoid the casting to NSLocale?

I'm aware I could write a Swift extension like this:

```
extension Locale {
    var extendedLanguageCode: String {
        (self as NSLocale).extendedLanguageCode
    }
}
```

However, that doesn't scale well. I have multiple properties and I'd need such glue code for all of them.

So I was looking for a switch to tell the compiler that for a specific class property it should not apply the bridging from NSLocale to Locale and actually return an NSLocale in Swift.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Possibly related, but unresolved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43022733/disable-automatic-bridging-in-some-cases

Comment: Interestingly, when I implement an Obj-C category on `NSString` I can call their methods just fine on Swift `String`s. Not sure why String/NSString behaves differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround with *cheating* obviously not preventing the autobridging of Foundation classes.

```
@interface MyLocale : NSLocale
@end

@interface NSLocale (YourCategory)
@property (class, nonatomic, nonnull, readonly) MyLocale *search;
@property (nonatomic, nonnull, readonly) NSString *extendedLanguageCode;
@end
```

Now in Swift you can use

```
_ = NSLocale.search.extendedLanguageCode
```

However I found a promising set of Clang attributes (look up the **Customizing Swift Import section**) here https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#swift-bridge.

**Update**
I was only able to effectively use

```
@property (class, nonatomic, nonnull, readonly) NSLocale* search __attribute__((swift_name("search2")));
```

&

```
@property (class, nonatomic, nonnull, readonly) NSLocale* search __attribute__((swift_private));
```

Essentially giving a custom Swift name to the property or making it private. Not particularly impressive.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the Clang attributes. Would love to know what they do in detail.

Comment: Added an update, nothing spectacular though.

Comment: Essentially what the NS_SWIFT_NAME and NS_REFINED_FOR_SWIFT macros do.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, you cannot get rid of the extension that forwards to the Objective-C implementation.

This is because Swift's `Locale` is a `ReferenceConvertible` over `NSLocale`, so any new methods/properties you add over `NSLocale` will need to be implemented on the Swift struct side too. This is the old classic "composition over inheritance" pattern.

I agree on some level on the scaling issue, however how many methods could you add over `NSLocale` to get into problems? :)