# How to get a NSString substring using an NSRange? Returning NSString, not String

Tags: swift

```
let nsString = NSString("Some string")
let nsRange = NSRange(5...10)
type(of: nsString.substring(with: nsRange))
// => String.Type
```

How can I do this, but returning an `NSString` instead of a `String`. I'm not looking for a solution that uses `Range<String.Index>`, I'm aware how to do it that way, but for what i'm doing the speed difference is noticeable. I'd like to keep things in the `NSString` world.

Benchmark code:

```
let string = String(repeating: "This is it. ", count: 10000)
let i1 = 19000
let i2 = 19020

// time computation
func tc(computation: (Int, Int) -> Void) {
    let startTime = DispatchTime.now()
    for i in 0..<100 {
        computation(i1 + i, i2 + i)
    }
    let endTime = DispatchTime.now()
    let ns = (endTime.uptimeNanoseconds - startTime.uptimeNanoseconds)
    print("Time: \(ns)")
}



tc { (s1, s2) in
  let start = string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: s1)
  let end = string.index(start, offsetBy: s2 - s1)
  string[start..<end]
}

tc { (s1, s2) in
  (string as NSString).substring(with: NSRange(s1..<s2))
}
```

`String block`:   `55_394_353ns`

`NSString block`: `1_389_647ns` - `39.86x faster`

Comment: This is not related directly but it would be helpful [swift-which-types-to-use-nsstring-or-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24038629/swift-which-types-to-use-nsstring-or-string)

Comment: @MohamadGhaithAlzin I don't agree that Swift's native types are more optimized. My tests show that getting a substring via String and Range<String.Index> takes 28x as long as doing so via an NSRange/NSString. 36.7ms vs 1.3ms for 100 iterations. That's not insignificant for a call that happens many times per keypress. And that test was for a short string, I imagine it's much worse for longer strings

Comment: @MohamadGhaithAlzin I did the test on a 200k char string, and the results get much worse. 583ms for String/Range<String.Index> vs 1.56ms for NSString/NSRange, (both for 100 iterations).

Comment: Are your tests done in an optimized/release build?

Comment: @Rob They're not, but unless Swift can do away with iterating each glyph in a string to convert an Int index to a String.Index, I see no way that this:
`let start = string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: s1); let end = string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: s2); let range = start..<end; string[range]`
will be faster than: `(string as NSString).substring(with: NSRange(s1...s2))`

Comment: @Rob I did an optimized build, 110k char string, 10 iterations. NSRange: 0.37ms, Range<String.Index>  25.6ms

Comment: Can you add your  benchmark code to the question?

Comment: Your two code blocks do not the same thing: the first one interprets `s1` and `s2` as `Character` counts (i.e. extended grapheme clusters), and the second one as UTF-16 code points counts (the units of `NSString`). The results are *different* if the string contains, Emojis, flags, or other characters outside of the “basic multilingual plane.”

Comment: Btw, the first version can made  a bit faster by computing the end index as `string.index(start, offsetBy: s2 - s1)`, but counting extended grapheme clusters is still slower than counting UTF-16 code units.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65570094/swift-obj-c-interop-prevent-bridging-of-foundation-classes

Comment: @MartinR Is there another way to do what I'm doing in the second block, but using `String`? To my understanding `String`'s way of of indexing forces me to use character counts rather than codepoints. The indexes I'll be getting from the server will be codepoint offsets rather than character offsets, so even asside from the performance difference, it seems like another reason to go with NSString.

Comment: For UTF-16 code point based indices you can do `let start = string.utf16.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: s1)` and `let end = string.utf16.index(start, offsetBy: s2 - s1)`, that should be considerably faster.

Comment: So this seems to be an XY-problem: What you actually want is not “make NSString substring using an NSString” but a fast Swift string subscripting based on UTF-16 indices. I would suggest that you update the question accordingly. “The indexes I'll be getting from the server will be codepoint offsets” is relevant information.

Comment: Martin is right. Using `utf16` with `String` is much faster, and is even an order of magnitude faster than `NSString` approach, using your benchmark.

Comment: And this assumes that you do not need the proper handling of characters represented by multiple unicode scalars. Consider `"‍‍‍"`. What is the length of that string? Of that `NSString`?

Comment: @Rob How are you getting that it's an order of magnitude faster than `NSString`? I just ran some tests and NSString is still 1/23 the speed of String, even using the utf16 code supplied by @MartinR.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for this @Rob. I was indeed able to repeat your results. I'll go with `String` using `utf16` as @MartinR suggested.

Answer (score -1):

Can't you cast NSString to String and vice versa?

```
let string = NSString("nsString") as String
let nsString = String("string") as NSString
```

Comment: Yes, but there's a cost to that, which is why I was looking for a solution that didn't require casting back and forth from `String`.

Answer (score -1):

These are being done 100 times, Right?

```
let start = string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: s1)
let end = string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: s2)
```

How about doing this instead:

```
let start = string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: s1)
let end = string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: s2)

tc {
    string[start..<end]
}
```

Which one is more optimized now?

Comment: The 100x was just to give more meaningful times in the benchmark than doing it once. In the actual code, it would be done an arbitrary amount of times, each with a different set of index numbers. I will update the code to reflect that.

Comment: @PeterR Since you are comparing the time it takes of getting `substring` from the original `string`, then it is more reasonable to compare only the functions for doing that!
Where is the logic right now behind getting `start` and `end` 100 times?

Comment: @PeterR Have you tried doing it as I mentioned only once?

Comment: What is a faster way to get a substring?